# How do I have my code recognize cells with a specific string STRUCTURE, while ignoring others?

Tags: vba, excel

So, here's what I'm facing.

I have a bit of vba code, that will find every cell in a single column containing a specific string. The words it looks for are in an array called totArray. This works well.

Problem is, when a word in the cell contains "SUBTOTAL" or something similar, it will still find it and copy it. Also, there will be words where TOTAL or TOTAAL aren't followed by numbers of unknown length.

Please see my code attached. How do I get it so that it will find every case where the cell contains TOTAL or TOTAAL but followed always by a non-common structure of numbers only.

```
Sub CopyValues()

Dim totArray As Variant
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim NoRows As Long
Dim DestNoRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Integer
Dim rngCells As Range
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim Found As Boolean

totArray = Array("TOTAAL ", "TOTAL")

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Input")
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Output")

NoRows = wsSource.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
DestNoRows = 2

For I = 1 To NoRows

    Set rngCells = wsSource.Range("A" & I)

    Found = False

    For J = 0 To UBound(totArray)
        Found = Found Or Not (rngCells.Find(totArray(J)) Is Nothing)
    Next J

    If Found Then
        rngCells.Copy wsDest.Range("B" & DestNoRows)

        DestNoRows = DestNoRows + 1
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide some relevant samples? I'd expect the Like oprator is your best bet.

Comment: Unfortunately, `.Find` doesn't support numeric only wildcard `#`. You will need to find your `.Find` and you could then check the response with `Like` which does support the `#` wildcard.

Comment: Should be easy, but to help us help you, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to better demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### To find a string with characters before/after the specified string:

You could put wildcards into the string, [see this documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-wildcard-characters-in-searches-ef94362e-9999-4350-ad74-4d2371110adb).

`"*TOTAL"` would find Sub**total**, Grand**total** etc as the asterisk wildcards any number of characters.

`"*TOTAL?????` would find any word with **total** at the end (like the example above) and with up to 5 characters after the word (as there are 5 question marks). For example: Sub**total123** or Sub**total54321**

`*TOTAL ?????` would find Sub**total 123** or Sub**total 54321** (notice the space can be used in the string between characters/wildcards).

Using this info you should be able to adjust your `Array` strings to work in your situation.

---

### To find an exact match to the specified string:

You should specify the `LookAt` parameter in your `.find` method.

e.g. `rngCells.Find(totArray(J), , , LookAt:= xlWhole)`.

> Using the LookAt function is pretty straightforward.
>
> 1. `xlWhole` means the search value must match the entire cell contents.
> 2. `xlPart` means the search value only has to match part of the cell

**Note:** In that example the `After` and `LookIn` parameters are omitted.
The `LookAt` parameter is the 4th parameter which is why there are blanks between the commas.

If you don't specify your parameters, Excel uses the parameters from the last search you ran either from using the `.Find` method via VBA *or* the GUI find window.

You can read more about each parameter, including the `LookAt` parameter [in this article about the vba find method.](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/)

Comment: So I got most of this down. Thank you for the help! But I'm wanting to find stuff WITHOUT the "Sub..." part. So ONLY when it states TOTAL do I want it to copy paste

Comment: @TimTuinstra I must have misunderstood the question sorry! You can specify what your find looks for. I'll edit the answer to include a detailed explanation on how to only find a specific sting omitting anything before/after it. To achieve it you need to specify the `LookAt` parameter in your `.Find`.